# Error on login for backend users with custom roles

Tags: ezpublish

I created custom role for some users, and I assigned role to particular user with content tree limitation. Like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsAmp.png)

Problem is that when that user log in, he get error like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFA69.png). Roles are working, so user can see his assigned content tree and work with it.

How can I solved this first screen? Even redirection on his content tree would do the job.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the user you assigned the role to, also has a basic role to access basic contribution functions. I usually have a "backoffice user" role which is assigned to every contributor (or group), which includes (without any limitation) :

- user/login on the admin siteaccess
- content/read on at least the root node : you need to be able to get "through" that node (and others if needed) to see the ones under it
- ezoe, ezjscore, ezmultiupload, ezfind, ezie etc
- content/(edit|remove|...) on contents which is owned by the user himself or its group

Hope this helps